# Laravel create table with raw string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

How can I **create** a **new table** in laravel 5.5 with a **raw DB string**?

```
$createTableSqlString =
  "CREATE TABLE $newTableName (
      product_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      ...
    )
    COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1;";
```

I know there is a **Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema** for making a new table,

```
Schema::connection('mysqlInvsys')->create(...);
```

But how should I define or give it the raw string `DB::raw($createTableSqlString)` ? I did not find any example in the [official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#creating-tables).

Comment: Why not use the build-in [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations) which is designed for this?

Comment: Because I have to use it an another mysql db what is used by other (not laravel) sites too, so I have to make it the "old", original way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Laravel provides functions for running raw SQL queries as shown [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries).

For table creation, you can use `DB::statement($createTableSqlString)`

Comment: Ohh thanks, its working! :) I'll accept this answer after the time limit.