# Create table in database with value from array object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i have an array object from query builder like this for example

```
$data = DB::table('list_cars')->select('car_name', 'car_id')->get();
```

I want to make new table with schema structure from result query builder $data above.
Is it possible to make it in laravel 8? result will be 2 field (car_name and car_id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use raw DB queries like for example:

```
DB::statement(
    "CREATE TABLE <tablename> AS "
    .DB::table('list_cars')->select('car_name', 'car_id')->toSQL()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, Sure you can use SQL raw in Laravel and create table**
*please attention this Question:*
[Laravel create table with raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50154249/laravel-create-table-with-raw-string)